# get_results from custom_table JOINED to (INNER JOIN of user table and usermeta table)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to query 3 tables in my WP DB at the same time using PURE SQL methods of `JOIN` and `INNER JOIN`.

I have a custom table named License which holds a user ID.

I want to start the query with the License table and query all columns there, then I need to get the data from the related user record in the WP_users table and push it to the same array, and then get all attached user meta fields to the user_id to that same array resulting a long array consisting of records built from the licenses table, related users table and related metadata.

I had tried to do the following query:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT $licenses_table.*, 
       $users_table.user_email, 
       DATE($users_table.user_registered) 
FROM $licenses_table 
JOIN (INNER JOIN  {$wpdb->usermeta} as m2 ON {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id = m2.user_id)", 
ARRAY_A);
```

What did I do wrong?

Please help

Comment: I have no knowledge of `PHP` but what does `JOIN (INNER JOIN` mean should you only use `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: I am trying to do some kind of nested Join. Thus I mean I am trying to join one table to a Join of the user table with the appropriate data saved in the usermeta table.

Comment: even so you first join licentabe with user_data and when you need as second also with an on clause

Comment: you should try to debug your query directly in the database before trying code it in php for wordpress

Comment: What is the proper way to do what I want in MYSQL?

Comment: @TsvielZaikman you should post table description, some datas and expected result , so we can build  the right query